# Primary Decomposition Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let V be a finite dimensional vector space over the field of complex numbers. Let T be a linear operator on V and let D be the diagonalizable part of T. Prove that if g is any polynomial with complex coefficients , then the diagonalizable part of g(T) is g(D).

Please, write the answer well explained. I have no idea how to start it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! If this is HW, it should be tagged as such (people will still help). Also, you must have some thoughts on the problem and tried something. What section of the book are you in, are there any theorems or the like that you learned.... Anything you have tried helps. Regards

Answer (score 2):

The point is that the difference $N=T-D$ (the nilpotent part) commutes with $D$, and products of type $DN$ are all nilpotent. The rest is highschool algebra.